# How to find the dependency that brought another dependency in MySQL or Redshift

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-redshift

There is two tables:

dependency_permission table:

| id | dependency_permission_id |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 |

user_permission table:

| id | user_id | permission_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11111 | 1 |
| 2 | 22222 | 4 |
| 3 | 22222 | 2 |
| 4 | 11111 | 2 |
| 5 | 33333 | 2 |

I want to write a query that finds all user_id's which have permissions depend on another permission the user doesn't have.
from the above data, users (22222 and 33333) should be returned, they don't have permission 1 which 2 depends on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may *left join* the 'user_permission' table with the 'dependency_permission' to get the 'dependency_permission_id' for each user 'permission_id', then use `NOT EXISTS` operator to check the existence of 'dependency_permission_id' for each user 'permission_id'.

```
with user_dependency_permission as
(
  select U.user_id, U.permission_id, D.dependency_permission_id
  from user_permission U left join dependency_permission D
  on U.permission_id = D.id 
)
select user_id, permission_id /* if you want to select only user_ids use distinct user_id*/
from user_dependency_permission T
where not exists(
                  select 1 from user_dependency_permission D
                  where T.user_id=D.user_id and 
                  D.permission_id=T.dependency_permission_id
                )
and T.dependency_permission_id is not null
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/F3qRXjZ5) on MySQL.